# java.lang.NullPointerException exception in Pentaho Report Designer when previewing a query

Tags: sql-server-2008, nullpointerexception, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am new to Report Designer, and am trying to create my first report.
I have created a JDBC Data Source, but when I try to preview the query, I get an error exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I can preview the results alright when my query does not have a 'join', so I am thinking it has something to do with that.
My sql query looks like this:

```
select
table1.column_x, --data type: tinyint
table2.column_y --data type: varchar(max)
from schema_name.table_one as table1
left join schema_name.table_two as table2
on table1.table_two_key = table2.key
```

It will return a preview result when I don't select anything from the second table:

```
select
table1.column_x
from schema_name.table_one as table1
left join schema_name.table_two as table2
on table1.table_two_key = table2.key
```

And it will also return a preview result when I choose the key to be selected from the second table:

```
select
table1.column_x,
table2.key --data type: bigint
from schema_name.table_one as table1
left join schema_name.table_two as table2
on table1.table_two_key = table2.key
```

I am using Report Designer 3.9.0.

There are 3 null point exceptions, and here is what I get from clicking on 'Copy to Clipboard':

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown
>   Source) at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown
>   Source) at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.background.DataPreviewDialog.showData(DataPreviewDialog.java:133)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog$PreviewAction.actionPerformed(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:141)
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:156)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:759)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:79)
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown
>   Source) at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown
>   Source) at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.background.DataPreviewDialog.showData(DataPreviewDialog.java:133)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog$PreviewAction.actionPerformed(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:141)
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:156)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:759)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:79)
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JTable.getToolTipText(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.ToolTipManager$insideTimerAction.actionPerformed(Unknown
>   Source) at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.background.DataPreviewDialog.showData(DataPreviewDialog.java:133)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog$PreviewAction.actionPerformed(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:141)
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown
>   Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source) at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:156)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:759)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:79)
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Your first query is the one that doesn't work?

Comment: Please post the full exception. Click the red cross on the bottom right corner and you'll see it all.

Comment: @Codek, I have posted the full exception.

Comment: I believe it seems to be an error within the JDK, there has been an issue filed at Pentaho's JIRA too with your exact same exception http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-2853